# (Oracle) Adding a constraint after a table has been made

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm relatively new to Databases and Oracle and I'm atempting to make a database for a project involving 2 tables; Klant(customer) and Account_. These 2 both have each others PK as a foreign key. Since this is the case I had to make the foreign keys after the creation of the tables, resulting in this

```
DROP TABLE KLANT CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE ACCOUNT_ CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE KLANT
 (
    "KlandId" INT PRIMARY KEY,
     "AccountId" INT,
     "Voornaam" VARCHAR2(64)NOT NULL,
     "Achternaam" VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
     "GENDER" CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'M' CHECK (UPPER(GENDER) in ('M','F')),   
     "Tussenvoegsels" VARCHAR2(16),
     "EmailAdres" VARCHAR2(64),
     "Land" VARCHAR2(64) DEFAULT 'Nederland',
     "Stad" VARCHAR2(64),
     "Adres" VARCHAR2(64),
     "Toevoeging" CHAR(1));

CREATE TABLE Account_
 (
     "AccountId" INT PRIMARY KEY,
     "KlantId_" INT,
     "GebruikersNaam" VARCHAR2(64)UNIQUE NOT NULL,
     "Wachtwoord" VARCHAR2(64)
 );

 ALTER TABLE KLANT
 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_accountId  FOREIGN KEY (AccountId) REFERENCES "Account_"(AccountId);

 ALTER TABLE Account_
 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_klantId FOREIGN KEY (KlantId_) REFERENCES "Klant"(KlantId);
```

This yielded me the following error:

```
Error starting at line : 39 in command -
ALTER TABLE KLANT
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_accountId  FOREIGN KEY (AccountId) REFERENCES "Account_"(AccountId)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ACCOUNTID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Sorry for all the dutch words :(

My question being: Where did I mess up, because it probably is something riduculously stupid.

Comment: I'm sorry I posted it before editing it fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     ALTER TABLE KLANT
 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_accountId  FOREIGN KEY ("AccountId") REFERENCES  Account_("AccountId");
```

Name of the Account_ Table should not be in double quotes. Same for the other table .

Comment: This works if also where to remove the quotes in my create querie. putting both instances of AccountId between code has given me the same result.

Comment: I edited my answer, Just try it the way it is and tell me if it works. While AccountId is better to be quoted, you are not allowed to keep table name (Account_) in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Quote AccountId.  In Oracle objects are generally uppercase.  When you use AccountId without quoting it, Oracle will look for ACCOUNTID.

Comment: Still returns me the same error, assuming you meant the AccountId with the brackets of the REFERENCES.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm a little curious (and this has nothing to do with your question) why you would have circular foreign key references in these tables.  In any case, you are saying that using REFERENCES "Account_"("AccountId") is failing?  Edit - You also have to do it in the FOREIGN KEY (AccountId) component.  Should read FOREIGN KEY ("AccountId")

Comment: This is the constraint as I have it now: 
ALTER TABLE KLANT
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_accountId  FOREIGN KEY ("AccountId") REFERENCES "Account_"("AccountId");
It now gives me the notification that the table or view simply does not exist. Which is strange, since I did get the confirmation of the Account_ table being created.

Comment: Generally speaking, it is unusual for an Oracle table and columns to be specified in mixed case.  I'm a little at a loss, honestly.  Oops.  Just noticed your table is "CREATE TABLE Account_".  This will yield an object named ACCOUNT_ in the system.  Try removing the quotes around "Account_"

Comment: This worked for me, but now it's confussing me even more. I got the same error on the second contrain when I used it like this: 

ALTER TABLE KLANT
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_accountId  FOREIGN KEY ("AccountId") REFERENCES Account_("AccountId");

ALTER TABLE Account_
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_klantId FOREIGN KEY ("KlantId_") REFERENCES "KLANT"("KlantId");

Yielding me this error:

SQL Error: ORA-00904: "KlantId": invalid identifier

From what I understand so far this means that it does not recognize the KlantId field in the KLANT tabel. But I'm clueless as to why, since KLANT("KlantId") does not work.

Comment: I think I get the concept now; When you use quotes Oracle will interpet it as raw text, allowing you to input whatever you want. If you don't use quotes Oracle will automaticly make your entry in all caps, making it so that if you use quotes inconsistent you will get errors like these.
Thank you for taking the time to help me

Comment: In your table create, you use "KlandId" with a "d" not a "t".  That is probably the issue.